# Context Menu in Finder not changeable via Preferences-Keyboard-Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to add the **New Terminal at Folder** feature to my finder right click menu. So I went to **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Keyboard Shortcuts** and checked the box named **New Terminal at Folder**.

The problem is that this has no effect on the finder context menu. There is no new entry even after a reboot.

If I make changes to other check boxes in the files and folders group this also has no effect at all. The context menu always looks the same no matter what i do.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to right-click the folder icon or list entry (when viewing the parent folder) and possibly open the *Services* sub menu. It's not possible to just right-click *anywhere in a folder window* and have that entry appear.

[image]

Comment: Hi, i saw it on a mac of a colleague. He had that "New Terminal at folder" on the very first level of his context menu. I do have an "Open file with TextWrangler" on that first level for example and i can see it checked in the Keyboard Shortcuts List. When i uncheck this as a test it does not disappear from the context menu and when i reboot it is checked in the settings again. So i am not able to make peristent changes. Any Idea?